# Firebase functions 'Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify'

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a custom email handler for my app and this is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",                           
  authDomain: "app.firebaseapp.com",         // Auth with popup/redirect
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com", // Realtime Database
  storageBucket: "app.appspot.com",          // Storage
  messagingSenderId: "123456789"   
});

const auth = firebase.auth()

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Website in progress...');
});

app.get('/auth/**', (request, response) => {
   // Get the action to complete.
   var mode = request.query.mode;
   // Get the one time code to authenticate.
   var actionCode = request.query.oobCode;
   // (Optional) Get the contine URL .
   var continueURL = request.query.continueURL; 
   // (Optional) Get the language code.
   var lang = request.query.lang;


   // What mode is it?
   switch (mode){
      case 'resetPassword':
        // Reset password - display UI and init backend code.
        response.send(resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang));
        break;
    case 'recoverEmail':
        // Recover email - display UI and init backend code.
        //recoverEmail(auth, actionCode, lang);
        break;
    case 'verifyEmail':
        // Verify email - display UI and init backend code. 
        //verifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueURL, lang);
        break;
    default:
        //response.send('Error')
        response.send("Internal server error - no API token.")
}
});

function resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang){
   var accountEmail;

   return auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(changePassword(actionCode))
}

function changePassword(actionCode){
   newPassword = 'newPassword'
   auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function(resp){
      return resp;
   }).catch(function(error){
      return error
   });
}


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And when I click the link from the password reset email that takes me the the website (website.com/auth/action.../) I receive this error from the functions log on firebase, I'm guessing it's when I try and return the response value but it can't because it's in JSON form? :

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
at ServerResponse.send (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at app.get (/srv/index.js:37:22)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Comment: What exactly did you intend to send to the client?  Right now, you are sending the promise returned by resetPassword, which is certainly not going to work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've been having issues with creating my custom email handler, I've just got my head around it and just wanted to see if what I was doing was actually working. I assume that is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what you're trying to send to the client, I can't tell you if the code here is correct.  I can tell what is the source of the issue, but I can't say anything other than that.  You'll probably need to learn how to deal with promises better.

Comment: @DougStevenson Honestly, I was just at school and it was nearing the end of lunch and I quickly rushed it just to see if I got any response back. Samthecodingman's answer below helped my fix this issue beautifully, thank you for the help though Doug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the circular object issue, it is probably related to this line:

```js
response.send(resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang));
```

Your `resetPassword` function is returning a Promise, which shouldn't be passed to `response.send(...)`. Instead, you should send the result of the Promise by chaining onto it.

```js
resetPassword(actionCode, continueURL, lang)
  .then((result) => response.send(result));
  .catch((error) => { // don't forget to handle errors
    console.log("ERROR:", error);
    response.sendStatus(500)
  });
```

You should also change

```js
return auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(changePassword(actionCode));
```

to

```js
return auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(() => changePassword(actionCode));
```

Otherwise, `then()` will try and incorrectly call the result of `changePassword(actionCode)` as if it were a function.

Comment: Oh, that's great! Thank you very much for that, I didn't know that.

Comment: @samethecodingman I cannot thank you enough for that, I've been here for days trying to figure this out, I guess I just needed a break ahahah. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Serialize circular references before sending the response

`Converting circular structure to JSON` is actually a very common type-error in JS and is not restricted to Firebase. Per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value):

> The [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) format per se doesn't support object references (although an [IETF draft exists](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03)), hence [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) doesn't try to solve them and fails accordingly.

Nevertheless, there are ways in which you can attempt to *stringify*. For instance, MDN provides an example in which you can use to go about this problem

```js
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());
```

The snippet above is the route I would recommend but in the event that you want something more *convenient* there exist an npm package ([`circular-structure-stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-structure-stringify)) that serializes circular references in a similar fashion. Just note that I haven't maintained this package for over 6 months, however, it should still apply as a possible solution to your issue.

Comment: @JKLleinne thank you for your answer, I shall try that out. what part of my code causes that error, out of interest?

Comment: No worries, I would suggest serializing what is passed in `response.send` to start